# Translate SQL query without FROM clause to LINQ

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

How to translate query like "select 1, 2" (i.e. without FROM clause) to LINQ statement?
Thanks!

I need to get permissions for a set of user groups. In SQL it looks like

```
SELECT * 
FROM Permission p 
INNER JOIN (SELECT GroupID 
            FROM [Group] 
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT 555) AS g 
ON (g.GroupID = p.GroupID)
```

In my case I need to programmatically add a certain code instead "555". I wouldn't like to write special SQL function for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you just want to create an anonymous type

```
var anonymous = new { Column1 = 1, Column2 = 2 };
```

Edit - Based on Comments

Depending on what your `Select` projection is you could do something simple like this:

If it is a `Int`:

```
var query = (from per in context.permissions
             select per).AsEnumerable()
             .Concat( new int[] { 1, 2 });
```

If it is a 'Class'

```
var query = (from per in context.permissions
             select per).AsEnumerable()
             .Concat(new CustomClass[] 
                      { 
                        new CustomClass()
                        {
                           Prop1= 1
                        },
                      }
                     );
```

You could also change `.Concat` to `.Union`

Comment: Aducci, thank you. But how I can UNION ALL it with other LINQ subquery results?

Comment: @Jim it would help if you asked the actual question you want the answer to, rather then a dozen question fragments.

Comment: @asawyer, thank you. I need to get permissions for a set of user groups. In SQL it looks like SELECT * FROM Permission p INNER JOIN (SELECT GroupID FROM [Group] UNION ALL SELECT 555) AS g ON (g.GroupID = p.GroupID) In my case I need to programmatically add a certain code instead "555". I wouldn't like to write special SQL function for that.

Comment: @Jim My suggestion would be to mark an answer complete here, as it does answer the original question, and then open a new question with that description.

Comment: You edition has completely answered my question, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need this to be linq?

```
var numbers = new int[] { 1, 2 };
```

I suppose

```
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1,2);
```